# use sed to extract the last portion of a string

Tags: regex, linux, sed

I have a string like the following:

```
ABC > D&E > FGH
```

and I want to extract the last portion

```
 FGH
```

How do I use sed to achieve that?

Comment: Why use sed? How about `echo 'ABC > D&E > FGH' | cut -f 3 -d '>'`?

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/.*\<//' file
```

This deletes everything upto the beginning of the last word.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -r 's/.*>([^>]+$)/\1/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/.* //' YourFile`
```

based on your sample and without other constraint liek space at the end, ...